# Is there a way to connect JST RCY female end to JST PH male end?

Tags: connector, wiring, lithium-polymer

I recently bought a lipo charger with a 2 pin JST RCY female end, however I did not realize the lipo I owned had a JST PH 2 male end (not RCY), so I was unable to connect the two and charge the battery.

I'm not sure what the differences between RCY and PH are, however since both of them have 2 pins and appear to be quite similar, is there a way I could still fit the two together somehow? Is there a way to modify the RCY female end so it fits the PH male end? Or would the best solution be just to buy a RCY to PH adapter or separate PH charger?

Answer (score 2):

RCY and PH have different pin spacing,  PH is 2.0mm and RCY is 2.5mm  so they won't connect for that reason (and probably other reasons)

The easiest way to connect these would be with an adapter cable, there seems to be several vendors with PH to RCY and RCY to PH adapter cables. Or you could replace the plug on the charger with a PH plug instead.